# I want to delete all the photos only in my drive like in D by using batch file can anyone help me

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
@echo off 
for /R "K:\" %%G in (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif) do DEL
echo off
```

I have make this but it's not working. I want it to find all images with following extensions and then delete them.

Comment: What "does not work"? You have no arguments for the `del` command; you should change it to `del %%G`...

Comment: As a debugging step, try replacing `DEL` (should really be DEL `%G%`) with `echo %G%`

Comment: @Arkadiy I don't think that `%G%` is a great idea. For loop iteration variables don't work like standard variables, they have things like expansion. Take a look at the output of 'for /?' in the cmd console to see what I mean.

Comment: @Epu I tried, %G% and %G both seem to work

Comment: You have to love it when a user who can't figure out the proper syntax for the `del` command then wants to run it globally on an entire drive. It makes it so easy to anticipate the next question (*I deleted a bunch of stuff I didn't mean to on my C:\ drive. How do I get it back?*), and you can pre-write the answer and just wait for it.

Answer (score 4):

The following does the same thing without a `for` loop. Add a `/q` to the `del` command to avoid the delete prompt (`del /q /s ...`).

```
pushd K:\
del /s *.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif
popd
```

Warning: this *will* delete all matching files from `K:\` so better be sure that's what you mean *before* you run it. You can first run `dir /s *.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif` to preview what files would be deleted.

Comment: +1 by me. Yes, opening a __command prompt window__ and running the command to use with parameter `/?` like `del /?` to get displayed the help for this command answers many questions like this one. It would be also possible to use a single command line: `del /A-D /Q /S K:\*.png K:\*.jpg K:\*.jpeg K:\*.gif`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing the second reference to the file in the %%G variable. The del command needs to be run with an argument like 'do DEL "%%G"'.

Try:

```
@echo off
for /R "K:\" %%G in (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif) do DEL "%%G"
```

Comment: The filename, directory name, or volume lable syntax is incorrect its showing in cmd

Comment: Maybe you need to quote the variable for paths with spaces? Updated the answer with quotes.

Comment: @echo off                                                                                                for /R "K:\" %%G in (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif) do DEL"%%G"echo off

Comment: @UmarGulzar does the command work for you with the added quotes? If so, I can update my answer to include the entire command.